# Integrating Fabric (Crashlytics) with C++

Tags: c++, ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have a C++ project that I would like to integrate with Fabric. Their documentation only covers Obj-C and Swift.

I've imported the SDK into the AppDelegate.cpp and I've included:

`#import <Fabric/Fabric.h> 
 #import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>`

But in the bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() method what would replace the 
`[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];` 
line?

Comment: Replace line `[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];` with this line `[Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];`.

Comment: `AppDelegate.cpp`?  That's not Objective-C++.

Comment: thanks @l00phole - updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are linking C++ code as static library you should set:

```
"Strip Debug Symbols During Copy" -> NO
"Strip Linked Product" -> NO
"Use Separate Strip" -> NO
```

In all libs. I have similar issue.
More info: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/advanced-setup.html